# apply a type of conditional left join

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

I have tables t1 and t2, both with two columns. Both tables contain customers and their transaction data. I want customer and transaction codes for those customers who are present in t1 but not in t2 and who have at least 1 transaction in t2.

```
CREATE TABLE t1 
(
    cust_code_1 VARCHAR(512),
    trans_code_1    VARCHAR(512)
);

INSERT INTO t1 (cust_code_1, trans_code_1) VALUES ('1', 'a');
INSERT INTO t1 (cust_code_1, trans_code_1) VALUES ('1', 'b');
INSERT INTO t1 (cust_code_1, trans_code_1) VALUES ('1', 'c');
INSERT INTO t1 (cust_code_1, trans_code_1) VALUES ('1', 'd');
INSERT INTO t1 (cust_code_1, trans_code_1) VALUES ('1', 'e');
INSERT INTO t1 (cust_code_1, trans_code_1) VALUES ('2', 'a');
INSERT INTO t1 (cust_code_1, trans_code_1) VALUES ('2', 'b');
INSERT INTO t1 (cust_code_1, trans_code_1) VALUES ('2', 'c');
INSERT INTO t1 (cust_code_1, trans_code_1) VALUES ('3', 'i');
INSERT INTO t1 (cust_code_1, trans_code_1) VALUES ('3', 'j');
INSERT INTO t1 (cust_code_1, trans_code_1) VALUES ('3', 'k');
INSERT INTO t1 (cust_code_1, trans_code_1) VALUES ('3', 'l');
INSERT INTO t1 (cust_code_1, trans_code_1) VALUES ('.', '.');
INSERT INTO t1 (cust_code_1, trans_code_1) VALUES ('.', '.');
INSERT INTO t1 (cust_code_1, trans_code_1) VALUES ('.', '.');
INSERT INTO t1 (cust_code_1, trans_code_1) VALUES ('.', '.');
```

```
CREATE TABLE t2 
(
    cust_code_2 VARCHAR(512),
    trans_code_2    VARCHAR(512)
);

INSERT INTO t2 (cust_code_2, trans_code_2) VALUES ('1', 'a');
INSERT INTO t2 (cust_code_2, trans_code_2) VALUES ('1', 'b');
INSERT INTO t2 (cust_code_2, trans_code_2) VALUES ('1', 'c');
INSERT INTO t2 (cust_code_2, trans_code_2) VALUES ('2', 'b');
```

Expected output

| cust_code_1 | trans_code_1 | cust_code_2 | trans_code_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | d | null | null |
| 1 | e | null | null |
| 2 | a | null | null |
| 2 | c | null | null |

Output which I am getting

| cust_code_1 | trans_code_1 | cust_code_2 | trans_code_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | d | null | null |
| 1 | e | null | null |
| 2 | a | null | null |
| 2 | c | null | null |
| 3 | i | null | null |
| 3 | j | null | null |
| 3 | k | null | null |
| 3 | l | null | null |
| . | . | . | . |
| . | . | . | . |
| . | . | . | . |

```
select * from t1 left join t2
on t1.cust_code_1=t2.cust_code_2
    and t1.trans_code_1=t2.trans_code_2 
where t2.cust_code_2 is null
```

I don't want cust_code_1 3 in the output. I want the output of left join but cust_code_2 should be available.
Because I have million of records but I need only those transactions where Cust code = 1 and Cust code = 2 which are not available in t2.

How do I get the expected output?

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask about 1 bad definition/query/function with the obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & ideally a [mre]. Then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter out that undesired records via only appending the below condition to the where clause:

```
and t1.cust_code_1 in (select tt2.cust_code_2 from t2 as tt2);
```

Thus, your result will contain only the records that have values in the cust_code_2 column.

Here is the full sql:

```
select * 
from t1 left join t2 on t1.cust_code_1 = t2.cust_code_2
    and t1.trans_code_1 = t2.trans_code_2 
where t2.cust_code_2 is null 
    and t1.cust_code_1 in (select tt2.cust_code_2 from t2 as tt2);
```

You can try it out in [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/377f45/6/0).